# Simple Event Trigger not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong with this super simple event trigger. I have cut out all of the other code I use so its just the event handlers and it still doesn't function.

```
    function go() 
    {
        console.log("Sending trigger");
        $(document).trigger("localize");
    }

    $(window).load(function () 
    {
        go();
        $(document).on("localize", function (e) {
            console.log("Trigger Received");
        })
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8XJL/

Comment: You're triggering the `localize` event before the event listener has been defined. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/F8XJL/2/) an update of your fiddle.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight good catch http://jsfiddle.net/F8XJL/3/

Comment: Like I said in my post, this is a really dumbed down version of the code, however, I had placed the trigger event after the event handler in the real code, it just was not inside of the window.load() event, thus causing the same issue as you see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your `go()` function before you set your event handler.

If you swap them, you should get what you're expecting:

```
$(window).load(function () 
{
    $(document).on("localize", function (e) {
        console.log("Trigger Received");
    });
    go();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8XJL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

> Like I said in my post, this is a really dumbed down version of the code, however, I had placed the trigger event after the event handler in the real code, it just was not inside of the window.load() event, thus causing the same issue as you see above.

Answer by [flockerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3389805/flockerman), the OP, upon realization of what had actually happened in the full code.